# How can search engine rankings be checked if search engines personalize search results?

Tags: seo, search-engines, ranking, google-ranking, rank-checkers

I see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble

So if I search for keywords related to my website to check the actual rank will the results be biased?

Comment: I removed the term "page rank" from this question.  Google PageRank is an internal metric that Google uses to determine how valuable a page is based on what other pages link to it.  It doesn't mean how well a page is ranking for some query like it was used here.

Comment: See also: [Google position changing on different computers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27167/google-position-changing-on-different-computers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't remove all the factors a search engine will use (the one most impacting you will be geographic targeting), you can get a relatively clean search result by using a separate browser. One with no browsing or search history, no cookies, and not logged into whichever search engine you're checking. That will remove much of the search engine's personalisation of the search results.

You can get around the geographic location targeting on Google by using a tool in Ads. Google Ads Diagnosis and Preview tool allows you to specify a location to search from, and gives you the organic results along with the paid ads.

Beyond that, you have to rely on Google Search Console's Average Position metric, which will tell you where your website appears in the search results for *some* searches.

There are third party tools which will run tests for you on an automated basis. My personal experience of these has been mixed and I'd hesitate to recommend any. Just search for Search Position Tracking and try a few out (they mostly offer free trials, either time or functionality limited) to see if they're of any use to you.

On final point, do bear in mind that your website's visitors *will* have their search results tailored by the search engines based on their search and browsing history. So what you see won't be what they see. It'll just be a fair approximation.

Comment: Is ip-level tracking a thing ?

Comment: @beppe9000 To the extent of geo-targeting, yes. For customisation? Unlikely. I've run tests directly and via a proxy and not noticed any differences (except the geographical targeting was set to the location of the proxy).